# Hybrid implementation for an entity and MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-classes, hybrid

Using Microsoft Entity Framework and MVC, I have the following requirement, implement an entity where some properties belong to a table within a sql server DB, and other properties are loaded from an XML column on the same table, I'd like to create properties in order to expose some values stored in the XML to the MVC view and controller.

Let's say I have the Entity "Laptop", loading columns from a table like processor and ram; for flexibility this table has an XML column with more data, I'd like to expose using properties of the "Laptop" Entity some of the values within the XML, like dvd, bluetooth, usb, etc.

I tried using a partial class with the name "Laptop", trying to declare and add the routines for the maintenance of the additional properties, however this is not working, the additional properties declared within this partial class are not visible on the "Laptop" entity for upper layers like MVC.

My problem is not related on how to extract the values from an XML, rely more on how to combine an Entity with custom properties, the entity is created automatically updating the model, I need a way to define the other properties somewhere else, not deleted automatically by the IDE at design time, for this reason my first thought was a partial class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of a `dynamic` object, so try the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class. You might have to use the `ExpandoObject` in conjunction with LINQ Expression trees for taking the data in the XML column and transforming it into a `fieldname`,`fieldvalue` array or another dynamic object.

[Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx) that might fit your use case: